# Enable ES6 in vim-snippets

Tags: vim

I'm trying to understand how should I enable the ES6 snippet in [`vim-snippets`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

If write `function` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, it generates this for me:

[image]

This is perfect.

But if I write [`af`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/javascript/javascript.es6.snippets#L19-L22) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it does *not* generate the arrow function.

Somehow I have to include that [`es6`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/javascript/javascript.es6.snippets) file, but I have no idea how...

How can I do that?

Comment: What snippet program are you using? UltiSnips or snipmate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) to load the `javascript-es6` snippets:

```
autocmd FileType js UltiSnipsAddFiletypes javascript-es6
```

From documentation:

> ```
>                       *FileType*
> FileType        When the 'filetype' option has been set.  The
>                 pattern is matched against the filetype.
>                 <afile> can be used for the name of the file
>                 where this option was set, and <amatch> for
>                 the new value of 'filetype'.
>                 See |filetypes|.
> ```

Refer to the [**Installation**](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets#installation) section for more information how to install that module.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of me writing a long answer to your query, I'll point you to this [post:](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/29/equipping-vim-for-javascript/)  which does a better job at explaining how to setup snippets for vim. After you setup vim with the plugins and Vundle to add your plugins, it's easy to find snippets for react, es6 etc...

```
`cd ~/.vim/bundle` and then just `git clone ./path/to/repo` or use `Vundle`
```

and add the plugins/packages through your ~/.vimrc file. Hope this helps.